# Как сделать insert новой ячейки, в новую секцию

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

Имеется пустой двоичый массив строк `fileprivate var stringArray: [[String]] = [[]]`

И ее табличное преставление

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
print("section \(stringArray.count)")
return stringArray.count
  }




  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("row \(stringArray[section].count)")
    return stringArray[section].count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = stringArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    return cell
  }
```

Так же имеется счетчик для создания новой секции

```
private var counterSection = 1
```

При нажатии на кнопку мы добавляем новую строку(рендомную), и делаем insert а таблицу.

Если количество ячеек больше 5 то, мы создаем новую секцию и уже туда начинаем вставлять новые строки.

```
@IBAction func addNewCell(_ sender: Any) {


let rendomString = randomStringWithLength(len: 8)

if stringArray[counterSection].count >= 5 {
  counterSection += 1;
  stringArray.append([String]())
}

stringArray[counterSection].append(rendomString)



tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(item: stringArray[counterSection].count - 1, section: stringArray.count)], with: .top)
tableView.endUpdates()


  }
```

Все прекрасно работает до того как надо создать новую секцию (т.е. до создания 5 строк)

После этого я получаю такую ошибку.

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 1, but there are only 1 sections after the update'**

Думаю это происходит, потому что не отрабатывает метод создания новой секции, но вот как это исправить не знаю...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По всей видимости нужно что-то такое:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
...
tableView.insertSections([counterSection], with: .fade)
...
tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(item: stringArray[counterSection].count - 1, section: stringArray.count)], with: .top)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, оказывается надо врезать секция, а потом ячейку...